# test class for the @auraenabled method that only call on button clicks

Tags: unit-test, aura, httpcalloutmock

I am facing issue in writing test class that has 1 method which only executed when  the lightning buttons get clicked.please suggest on this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the issue? if you have written code for test method post that along with class code

Answer (score 3):

You test an `@AuraEnabled` by calling it directly from your test:

```
public YourClass {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}

@IsTest
private YourClassTest {
    @IsTest
    static void testDoSomething() {
        System.assertEquals('...', YourClass.doSomething());
        ...
    }
}
```

The serialization to and from the client parts is handled by the platform and does not need to be tested by you.

Only if your `@AuraEnabled` method makes its own HTTP callouts would also need to setup a [HttpCalloutMock](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html).

Comment: @auraenabled   public void getAllinfo(){ public void getCalloutsMethods(){} public void getButtonClickMethod(){}}@auraenabled public void getButtonClickMethod(){} But I am using this method inside a method.Can you help me on this.